# How can I pass a RadioGroup from one activity to another one?

Tags: android

Can someone please help me how to pass RadioGroup with RadioButtons with selected option passed from one activity to another activity.

**Say for Ex:** In activity1, I am building a RadioGroup with RadioButtons. The text of these RadioButtons is dynamic pulled from DB. The user can select any of the RadioButtons.

Now, how I can pass this RadioGroup along with Buttons(including selected option) to Activity2.

Comment: you dont pass any `View`s, you can only pass data instead

Comment: pass the data of the view using Intent from one activity to another

Comment: You can define a layout with reusable view and use <include> option to add the layout with the view in multiple layout.

Comment: I know that we can pass data from one activity to another activity using Intent, but how can i pass these objects. Say Survey app. Whatever options with the selected user choices i want to display in the next activity. How can i do this?

Comment: @Chithra, can you please provide some pointers or inputs. I am pretty new to android and trying for one sample app.

Comment: Be more specific what actually you are trying to pass between activities. Is it just int, String, boolean and etc or it's your custom object class which stores the data?

Comment: @hardartcore, please check my previous comment. I added more info. Say we are developing an "User Survey" app. User is provided with multiple questions(say radio group with buttons). In Activity1, i load all these questions with options dynamically. Once all questions are over, then in Activity2, i would like to show what questions and what option in each question was chosen by a user. For that, how can i pass list of these RadioGroups from Activity1 to Activity2?

Comment: You are not going to pass your views from Activity 1 to Activity 2 that's something that you should forget about! You pass some sort of data depending on your implementation, pass your values which indicates selected options and than in activity 2 you repopulate your UI (maybe use the same xml layout or something else again depends on your implementation and design).

Comment: I solve this problem by using Parcelable.

Answer (score 0):

Pass data using `intent` from one activity to another.

```
intent.putExtra("radiovalue", "abc" );
startactivity(intent);
```